# How check an object's every key and value if null or undefined with ES6?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to check an objects every entry's key and value in a if condition, but i cannot understand my result. What is the problem? Why is an undefined not false with "??" ?

```
const object = {undefined: "foo", B: "Bazz"}
console.log(Object.entries(object).every(([key, value]) => !!key && !!value))

//true

const object2 = {undefined: null, B: "Bazz"}
console.log(Object.entries(object2).every(([key, value]) => !!key && !!value)) 

//false
```

Comment: keys are string or symbols of objects. `'undefined'` is a string. btw, why do you expect a different result?

Comment: I wanted to test what would happen if i get undefined as a key. i didn't know its managed like a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The propertie names of objects are strings or `Symbol`. To check the value, you could take an array of unwanted strings and check with `includes`.

```js
const
    check = object => Object
        .entries(object)
        .every(([key, value]) => !['', 'null', 'undefined'].includes(key) && value);

console.log(check({ a: "foo", B: "Bazz" }));
console.log(check({ undefined: "foo", B: "Bazz" }));
console.log(check({ undefined: null, B: "Bazz" }));
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot actually set the key to `undefined`. When you do `{ undefined: "foo" }`, you are actually setting the key to the string `"undefined"`. It is essentially the same as `{ "undefined": "foo" }`

`!!"undefined" && !!"foo"` => `true && true` => `true` because non-empty strings are truthy

`!!"undefined" && !!null` => `true && false` => `false` because `null` is falsy